# Is it possible to escape a colon in batch?

Tags: batch-file, escaping

I am a advanced-ish batch programmer, and know about escape characters. However, after hours of searching, I can't find a answer to this. Here is my code snippet:

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,%a%) do (
set /a e=%%a*100/%a%
cls
echo %date%%time% Creating %a%x%b% matrix using %c%...
echo !e!%% complete.
for /l %%b in (1,1,%b%) do set /a a%%a%%b=%%a%c%%%b
)
```

This works fine, but the next snippet gives me a ": was unexpected at this time." error.

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,%a%) do (
set /a e=%%a*100/%a%
cls
echo %date%%time% Storing %a%x%b% matrix using %c% to %d%
echo !e!%% complete.
for /l %%b in (1,1,%b%) do echo Cell (%%a,%%b): !a%%a%%b!>>%d% 
)
```

Please help. I don't know how to make the colon work.

Answer (score 3):

```
for /l %%b in (1,1,%b%) do echo Cell ^(%%a,%%b^): !a%%a%%b!>>%d%
```

should give you the result you want.

Interestingly, it's not the colon that needs escaping, but the parentheses. This is because batch sees the `)` inside the outer for loop and thinks that's the end of the loop there.

Comment: Correct, but the escaping of the opening parenthesis isn't necessary, but still harmless